# Unable to align extruded text to grid bottom

Tags: 3d-printing

So I am busy modelling a simple keyring I would like to 3D Print. I add text (Each letter is a separate text object so I can extrude them to different "heights") so that the text alternates one high, one low:

[image]

The Issue I am having is that the characters are not all aligned at the bottom, and I need to print the bottom of all characters as a single layer on the 3d Printer. They need to all be aligned on the yellow line basically:

[image]

What would be the easiest way to align all the characters to the bottom of the grid so that the bottom layer will be one layer for all characters when 3D Printing?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a driver to *Z Location*:

[image]

However, this can cause glitching in *Edit Mode*:
[image]

You could therefore use a Python script to align objects whenever you need - go to scripting tab, create a new file, paste the below and press the *Play* [image] button to realign:

```
import bpy

aligned_objects = ['Cube']

for name in aligned_objects:
    aligned_object = bpy.data.objects[name]
    aligned_object.location.z = - aligned_object.bound_box[0][2]
```